# django model.objects.filter(mydate__month=date.today().month) not working

Tags: django, filter, model, django-queryset

I've been staring at this for a bit and can't see the issue. Basically I have a number of views and filter by different date combinations, for example by this year, or this month or even today etc. I'm struggling with one view, the filter by this month.

For the current year filter, this works:

```
queryset = mymodel.objects.filter(mydate__year=date.today().year).order_by('field')
```

However, trying this approach for the current month doesn't:

```
queryset = mymodel.objects.filter(mydate__month=date.today().month).order_by('field')
```

An exception is thrown, which basically is summarised as:

```
TypeError at /core/tcCoreVendor/
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I can work around it by doing:

```
month = date.today().month
where = "%(month)s = MONTH(mtime)" % {'month': month}
queryset = mymodel.objects.extra(where=[where])
```

but that seems crazy!

Any help or advice much appreciated!

Here's the model:

```
class tcCore_vendor(models.Model):
    '''
    tcCore_vendor

    Model that represents the vendors of hardware, software and applications etc.
    '''
    uid = models.CharField(db_column='uid', max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.TextField(db_column='address', blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(db_column='contactnumber', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.TextField(db_column='image', blank=True, null=True)
    mtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        app_label = 'tcCore'
        db_table = 'tc_core_vendor'
        ordering = ['name']
```

Here's the view:

```
class tcCore_vendor_viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API for viewing and editing vendors.
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = tcCore.serializers.tcCore_vendor_serializer
    search_fields = ('name', )
    ordering_fields = ('name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """ Override the standard query set to provide some flexibility on the result set. """

        view = self.request.query_params.get('view', None)
        if view is not None:
            if int(view) == 1: # Any date
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.all().order_by('name')
            elif int(view) == 2: # Today
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.filter(mtime__date=date.today()).order_by('name')
            elif int(view) == 3: # Past 7 days
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.filter(mtime__range=[timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7),  timezone.now()]).order_by('name')
            elif int(view) == 4: # This month
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.filter(mtime__month__lte=date.today().month).order_by('name')
            elif int(view) == 5: # This year
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.filter(mtime__year=date.today().year).order_by('name')
            else: # No view provided
                queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.all().order_by('name')
        else: # No view provided
            queryset = tcCore.models.tcCore_vendor.objects.all().order_by('name')

        return queryset

    def get_view_name(self):
        name = "tcCoreVendor"
        suffix = getattr(self, 'suffix', None)
        if suffix:
            name += ' ' + suffix
        return name
```

Here's the full trace:

```
TypeError at /core/tcCoreVendor/
not all arguments converted during string formatting

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/tcCoreVendor/?view=4
Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Executable: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path: ['/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/Google Drive/GitHub/company_name', '/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python36.zip', '/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6', '/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Fri, 18 May 2018 08:23:17 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'corsheaders',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'django_filters',
 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
 'tcCore.apps.tcCoreConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['raven.contrib.django.middleware.DjangoRestFrameworkCompatMiddleware',
 'raven.contrib.django.middleware.SentryMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'company_name.tcMiddleware.middleware']


Traceback:

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  85.             return self.object_list.count()

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  387.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  491.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  476.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1051.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  459.                 where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  80.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in as_sql
  160.         lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in process_lhs
  155.             db_type, field_internal_type) % lhs_sql

During handling of the above exception (not all arguments converted during string formatting), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  103.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  42.         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in paginate_queryset
  173.         return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/pagination.py" in paginate_queryset
  204.             self.page = paginator.page(page_number)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  65.         number = self.validate_number(number)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  43.         if number > self.num_pages:

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  36.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in num_pages
  95.         if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  36.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  90.             return len(self.object_list)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1051.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  459.                 where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  80.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  391.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in as_sql
  160.         lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)

File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/company_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in process_lhs
  155.             db_type, field_internal_type) % lhs_sql
```

Comment: In your title you specified `__date` instead of `__month`. At what part is this an error?

Comment: Corrected, thanks for spotting.

Comment: currently test on my model `Mymodel.objects.filter(start_date__month=date.today().month).count()` all works fine. Please show your model and full error trace.
my django==1.10, Python 3.5.3

Comment: @LeeHarding: what version of Django do you use? Perhaps this is a known bug that was solved in a next version.

Comment: @BearBrown added trace.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm using Django Version: 2.0.2 and Python Version: 3.6.5

Comment: What database backend are you using? Looking at the source for `process_lhs()` it seems that the string being formatted comes from a call to the backend. Are you using an officially supported backend, or a 3rd-party backend?

Comment: @WillKeeling It's MySQL, v5.6.39 hosting on AWS. It's the Oracle connector v2.1.7

Comment: @WillKeeling, sorry I meant Oracle MySQL connector v8.0.11 (platform independent version)

Comment: Thanks. Also, what is the `ENGINE` set to in the `DATABASES` section in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling it's set to mysql.connector.django